# Topic Modeling, Gensim, Python, Getting Topic Models According to fixed IDs or Linked Data

Tags: python-3.x, gensim, topic-modeling

I have a question about topic modeling via python and gensim library: when I run the following code, it works well and comes up with the related topics but I want to see each topic per document listed in the .csv file but it shuffles. For example, 1st topic is from the 2nd document but the 2nd topic is from the 1st document, and the 3rd is from the 3rd one. And when I run the same code, it shuffles again. How can I fix that and get topics per document or/and linked topics directly to the Ids or authors of the documents that could be listed in the 1st column?

## Codes:

## Step 1:

```
 import nltk
 import csv
 import re
 import nltk.corpus
 import gensim
 from gensim import corpora
 from nltk.corpus import stopwords
 from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
 import string
```

## Step 2: Loading data and Processing

```
 doc_complete = open('/home/erdal/Desktop/big_data/abstract1.csv', 'r').readlines()
 stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
 exclude = set(string.punctuation)
 lemma = WordNetLemmatizer()
 def clean(doc):
    stop_free = " ".join([i for i in doc.lower().split() if i not in stop])
    punc_free = ''.join(ch for ch in stop_free if ch not in exclude)
    normalized = " ".join(lemma.lemmatize(word) for word in punc_free.split())
    return normalized
    doc_clean = [clean(doc).split() for doc in doc_complete]
    print(doc_clean)
    dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(doc_clean)
    doc_term_matrix = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in doc_clean]
    Lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel
    ldamodel = Lda(doc_term_matrix, num_topics=3, id2word = dictionary, passes=50)
    print(ldamodel.print_topics(num_topics=3, num_words=3))
```

## Step 3: Printing out the topics

```
  myData = ldamodel.print_topics(num_topics=3, num_words=3)
  myFile = open('/home/erdal/Desktop/big_data/all_data_1_topics.csv', 'w')
  with myFile:
   writer = csv.writer(myFile)
   writer.writerows(myData)
   print("Writing complete")
```

## Topics:

```
 [(0, '0.036*"learning" + 0.036*"student" + 0.026*"intergroup"'), (1, '0.005*"abstract" + 0.005*"significant" + 0.005*"using"'), (2, '0.042*"clickers" + 0.027*"motivation" + 0.027*"student"')]
```